# Binary expansion and partition numbers

Tags: tips, binary, fastest-code, integer-partitions

Not sure if it's correct to ask such a question on this site, but let's try.

Let **a(n)** be a sequence of positive integer such that **a(1) = 1**. To reproduce the sequence **a(n)** through itself, use the following rule: if binary **1xyz** is a term then so are **110xyz** and **1XYZ** where the last one is the same as **1xyz** with rewrite **1 -> 10**.

The sequence begins with

**1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 26, 32, 40, 48, 52**

These numbers in binary:

```
[1]
[1, 0]
[1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

Here are examples:

- **1 -> 10** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **10 -> 100** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **1 -> 110** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**
- **100 -> 1000** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **10 -> 1100** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**
- **1000 -> 10000** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **110 -> 10100** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **100 -> 11000** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**
- **110 -> 11010** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**
- **10000 -> 100000** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **1100 -> 101000** by the rule **1xyz -> 1XYZ** (rewrite **1 -> 10**)
- **1000 -> 110000** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**
- **1100 -> 110100** by the rule **1xyz -> 110xyz**

It appears that positions of the powers of **2** in **a(n)** are partition numbers ([A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041)).

I tried to write an efficient PARI/GP program to generate a list of the first **n** terms and this is what I got:

```
b1(n) = my(L = logint(n, 2), A = n); A -= 2^L; L - if(A==0, 1, logint(A, 2))
upto(n) = my(v1, v2); v1 = vector(n, i, if(i < 3, i)); v2 = [1, 2];  my(k = 2, j = 1, q = 0); for(i = 3, n, my(A = v2[j] + q); if(A >= v2[k-1], k++; v1[i] = 2^(k-1); j=k\2; q = 0; v2 = concat(v2, i), v1[i] = v1[A] + 2^(j-1) + 2^(k - 1); if((k - j - 2) >= b1(v1[A+1]), j++; q = 0, q++))); v1
```

Is there a way to write a simpler program (that is, such a program which returns same number of values faster than my program given above)?

Comment: How do you define simpler? All challenges on this site, including tips, need an objective winning criteria

Comment: @mousetail, thank you for comment! Sorry, I'm still new here. Done.

Comment: I don't get it, what order?

Comment: or can you give first few elements?

Comment: @l4m2, thank you for comment! Done.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Comment: These seem to be binary expansions where the lengths of the runs of zeroes are in sorted order. Specifically, ones of the form \$110^a10^b10^c\cdots\$ where \$1\leq a \leq b \leq c \cdots\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/)

Port of @l4m2's c++ answer in Rust.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBdj5swEHzPr9i7hxPcQQS5a1SROC@V@tq3qlIUVQ5dUiuOjYyhUVP@eunahEuI@rUSMp4d7@yMqSvbdYWCQuugzEA8zyI4ZlCns7cRyO0ZKXWVwcOhtlBX4jtGwI05Ax8xXzr2KoTTBKhEAY/EhxVzrKlEFQwtVwZtbdTC39vJ8KJ0dLm94tHbtZuzAQbHxSvsRz8xSEcTCm1gD0JBENCQJ0jD6ZSV4dRgMxL3LiGGPZmEH8ROgVfebAjLJfS9MIwcgYS8z3BQaieUU6Vlg8Ff7Eu04Bo@Mp8WGUgW414P9ZjW5dWGLos/h@dqa5DvL4G0Y3MR3HgiJIn6XW8cuSpHWVKaZPHAxUXVraxo3TfJ5yRx39gJp1aD@d06WYDa9L0@Iq/Iz1KjNwJeJb99FRIJWJLGxWVphLJS3QX3pyydtXDKknT@qT0f9xEIcsnXYgOrFcxfQu93/jKAD5Ac39/UwLmyLuCRwWyw/l@6Kk69CJ2/0/bwP9TbrvuZF5Lvqi5@p0sbS2xQsme6SatZwS39WW52aOO8rJniVjRIWK6/4A5VXCthK5bOCRIqN3hAZblk1tTE@vAL)

```rust
fn foo(p: i32, x: u128, lb: i32, pos: &mut usize, arr: &mut Vec<u128>) {
    if *pos >= arr.len() {
        return;
    }

    if p >= lb {
        arr[*pos] = x;
        *pos += 1;
    }

    for k in ((lb + 1)..=p).rev() {
        foo(p - k, x | ((1 as u128) << (p - k)), k, pos, arr);
    }
}
fn solve(arr: &mut Vec<u128>) {
    let mut pos: usize = 0;
    let mut p = 0;

    loop {
        if pos >= arr.len() {
            break;
        }
        foo(p, (1 as u128) << p, 0, &mut pos, arr);
        p += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let n = 50_000_00;
    let mut a = vec![0; n];
    solve(&mut a);
    
    let mut i = 1;
    while i < n {
        println!("{:12} {:016X}{:016X}", i, (a[i] >> 64) as u64, (a[i] & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) as u64);
        i *= 2;
    }
    println!("{:12} {:016X}{:016X}", n-1, (a[n-1] >> 64) as u64, (a[n-1] & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) as u64);
}
```

Comment: Why isn't `26` in your output? Also, should `50_000_00` have an extra `0`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 52 bytes, 10,000 in ~10s on TIO

```
⊞υ¹ＦＮ«≔⌊υι⟦Ｉι⟧≔⁻υ⟦ι⟧υ≔⍘ι²ι⊞υ⍘⪫⪪ι1¦10²⊞υ⍘⁺110✂ι¹Ｌι¹¦²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY89C8IwEIZn@ytCpwtEaLo6qZOiUuhYOsQS24M0LflwEX97TMCPLt5wB3fP@95dNwjTTUKFUHk7gGeE0012mwyBg569u/jxKg1QSh7Zamst9hrOqHH0I3jKCEZ6VRnUDpq9sA6Qtqn1Q71Nrg22kfaL0U5YWbuo7AEZKb9e7zMW4@OEGupZoUtkznOacpFKSf9oKhX35jxSjNQKO5mknJGT1L0b4pXp0Y/BMwRexAjru3oB) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: For each number, generates the two derived numbers, and then takes the minimum number generated for the next number.

```
⊞υ¹
```

Start with `1`.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Generate `n` numbers.

```
≔⌊υι
```

Get the next minimum.

```
⟦Ｉι⟧
```

Write it to the canvas.

```
≔⁻υ⟦ι⟧υ
```

Remove it from the list.

```
≔⍘ι²ι
```

Convert it to binary.

```
⊞υ⍘⪫⪪ι1¦10²
```

Change all `1`s into `10`s, convert from binary, and push the result to the list.

```
⊞υ⍘⁺110✂ι¹Ｌι¹¦²
```

Remove the leading `1`, prefix `110`, convert from binary, and push the result to the list.